# How would I be able to cut out a section of a string if I know I can find both the beginning and the end of a string?

Tags: python, string, find

I am trying to look for the beginning of a string, the end of the string, and then use that information to store the middle of the string into a variable.

However, I am not sure why the first `if` statement does not pass. See below:

```
str = "start_message_end"

# QUESTION: Why does this test below not pass?
if str.find("start_"):
    print "Found the start"

# This works fine
if str.find("_end"):
    print "Found the end"

# This was just another test
if str.find("message"):
    print "Found the message"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) **returns the index**:

```
>>> "start_message_end".find("start_")
0
```

In a Boolean context, `0` evaluates to `False`:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Instead, I think you want [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
>>> "start_message_end".startswith("start_")
True
```

You can then use a slice (see e.g. [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)) to extract the middle of the string:

```
>>> s = "start_message_end"
>>> if s.startswith("start_") and s.endswith("_end"):
    print s[6:-4]


message
```

Comment: As an addition: to only check if a string exists within another one without needing to get the position, one can use `"start" in "start_message_end"`, which would returns `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon.

However, lets say my string has more information in it now, i.e:

    str = "blahblahblah_start_message_end_blahblahblah"

How would I be able to find the the sections of the string which have "start" and "end", and then how would i be able to slice out the message into a variable if I do not know the indices?

Comment: @suboo8491 in that case, note that `'nostart'.find('start_')` will return `-1`, and work from there.